# Javascript mobile device width check and class remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, width, removeclass

I need to remove some classes from my site if the device width is under 1200 px (because of the mobile view).

I tried to use Javascript, this method worked fine:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
var current_width = $(window).width();
if(current_width < 1200)
  $('a').removeClass("expand");
  $( ".effects clearfix" ).remove();
  $( ".overlay" ).remove();
  $('#removeimg').removeClass('img').addClass('imgmobile');});
```

But the problem is, this works only if I resize the window. So if I open the site using my smartphone (Android 4.3, Chrome) the script does not work.

I tried to write this code but I failed:

```
function checkWidth() {
var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
    if (window.innerWidth < 1200)  {
        $('#removeimg').removeClass('img').addClass('imgmobile');     
    }
    if (window.innerWidth < 1200) {
        $( ".effects clearfix" ).remove();    
    }
    if (window.innerWidth < 1200) {
        $( ".overlay" ).remove();    
    }
    if (window.innerWidth < 1200) {
        $('a').removeClass("expand");  
    }
```

How can I check the device width and set these classes under 1200 px?
(I also tried to modify/set initial values/ the css with media queries but unfortunately I still need to remove the classes :( )

Thank you for any idea.

Comment: Most likely your function is never getting called. You'll need an event to trigger it, this can be the document.ready. The resize is firing because every time you resize the browser the function fires.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the window in a jquery element. That should work for you. You'll also need an event to trigger this function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if ($(window).innerWidth() < 1200)  {
            $('#removeimg').removeClass('img').addClass('imgmobile');     
        }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this code works well but it seems like the Android Chrome still ignores the javascript code or something. My problem is an img element with a link, some classes does not allow to click on it on mobile browsers. If I manually remove these classes the img link works well. But I need to keep them for the non-mobile devices, this is why I thought if I remove with javascript for the mobile browsers it will be fine. :( Maybe I should give up all classes (they make an animation img hover effect what causes problem on mobile devices).

Answer (score 0):

You had placed code inside resize function, that's it's only working on resize of window. Call in once in ready function and once in resize too.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be to use separate classes and use `display: show` and `display: hide` in a media query in the CSS.

This works well across mobile platforms, but you may have to do multiple media queries.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I already tried this way but I figurated out that I need to completely remove the classes.